# How to Get the Server Address of the server that data is pulled from

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I know we have it in Java driver using cursor.getServerAddress(). However, I couldn't find any relevant call in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, after digging a little deeper though through the C# driver source code (and the Java source code to see what it was doing), the actual server address that was used as part of the fetch is hidden away in the Enumerator as a private member (`_serverInstance`).

In particular, it's hidden away in a class called the `MongoCursorEnumerator`. Unfortunately, there isn't an "honest" way of getting to it. You could use .NET reflection I suppose to get to it, but that's generally not a good idea, especially with code you don't own. If you wanted to have a custom fork of the driver, you could easily add it as a new property. You might want to add an issue [here](https://jira.mongodb.org).

In general, you can get the instances used by the MongoDB connection, as they are available on the `MongoServerInstance` class, the `Address` property.

```
var client = new MongoClient();
var server = client.GetServer();
// server.Instance.Address
```

[Documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/?topic=html/4367254d-0112-f256-be8e-cc97ebc189ab.htm)

However, in your case you can also get it from the `cursor` via the `Server` property:

```
cursor.Server.Instance.Address.Host
```

or

```
cursor.Server.Instances[]
```

[Cursor Server Documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/?topic=html/ec0ea469-51cb-255a-ee27-5b814f0565ff.htm)

The C# driver interestingly throws and exception when more than one Instance is available. So, if you don't know how many instances there are, you either need to handle the `exception` (`InvalidOperationException`), or always use the `Instances[]` property to return the associated instances.

Comment: Thanks WiredPrairie. I tried it but it is not the one I am looking for. It returns IP address in the connection string. In my case, I connect to a replicaset which have 2 secondary servers. I want to get the server address of the server that data is pulled from. I use ReadPreference.Secondary mode. Drivers will do round robin and route query to servers at the time we read document.

Comment: @TuongHuynh - Ahh. I misunderstood. It's nearly identical. See edit (via the `cursor.Server.Address` property.

Comment: @TuongHuynh - What happens when you use `Instances`?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Actually, there is no cursor.Server.Address property. I tried to use cursor.Server.Instance.Address but I got the following error when access cursor.Server.Address.In:  
  
"Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Instance property cannot be used when there is more than one instance. ...."  
  
Also, cursor.Server.Instances.Length return 3. I use: mongostat -h xxx --discover to check where is the query actual execute and see that it execute on one of secondary servers. It means the query only execute on 1 server.

Comment: OK, I did a bit more digging than I'd expected would be needed. Turns out the specific property you want hasn't been exposed. I'd thought the cursor had it, but it wasn't actually the server being used. I edited my answer to include the details.